# Calling Center Software

Tags: software-recommendation, phone

I am looking for an app that can do the following in a PC:

1. Receive telephone calls and via the computer, tell the caller some information.
2. Optionally have a "For X service, dial 1... For Y service, dial 2..."
3. Shows stats about calls

Is there a kind of software in Ubuntu for this purpose?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is and it's called [Asterisk](http://www.asterisk.org/).

It's a PBX.  If it's your first time using and configuring asterisk, I would HIGHLY recommend using [Trixbox](http://www.trixbox.com/) instead of Ubuntu until you get used to it (it can be a pain to set up).  Once you're comfortable, then go back and get a juju script built for it or something ;)

It is available in software center as well, just for the record.  I've never had much luck with asterisk not from source though.